# How to update template views in Odoo while developing?

Tags: odoo

Is there an easy way for updating changes made in a template view when developing a module? Or what's the best approach for having a preview of what I'm coding?

I currently upgrade the module each time I change the template, but it costs me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run Odoo with the command-line --dev option, you have the following additional arguments:

**all**: all the features below are activated

**XML**: read template qweb from XML file directly instead of a database. Once a template has been modified in the database, it will be not be read from the XML file until the next update/init.

**reload**: restart the server when python file is updated (may not be detected depending on the text editor used)

**qweb**: break in the evaluation of qweb template when a node contains t-debug='debugger'

**(i)p(u)db**: start the chosen python debugger in the code when an unexpected error is raised before logging and returning the error.

See this [Click Here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/cmdline.html#advanced-options)

Thanks